# How do I visualize the author's post from the front end?

Tags: php, buddypress

Currently posts are created automatically with an importer and I want the user to be able to see their own post.
I already have the code to display the personalized post and the button to modify it. But how do I show it in a link in the menu or widget?
Thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean you want a link to an archive of author's posts?

Comment: Yes. A link to see the publication that that user created. I only know links where all the publications of authors are seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of posts created by each user using /author/{username}
Eg : https://www.wpbeginner.com/author/wpbeginner/